# When I configure onBackpressureError in WebFlux, it raises an error based on specific conditions

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I'm currently studying webflux Backpressure, and I'm not sure about the criteria for triggering an error when setting onBackpressureError. When testing with the provided source code, I receive data only up to 255, and from 256 onwards, an error occurs. When examining the decompiled code, it seems that the error occurs when DropSubscriber.requested becomes 0. I'm wondering if there is any correlation between these factors.

```java
class BackpressureErrorTest {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BackpressureErrorTest.class);

    @Test
    void given_when_then() throws InterruptedException {
        Flux
                .interval(Duration.ofMillis(1L))
                .onBackpressureError()
                .doOnNext(data -> log.info("# doOnNext: {}", data))
                .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .subscribe(data -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    log.info("# onNext: {}", data);
                }, error -> log.error("# onError", error));

        Thread.sleep(2000L);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get `Exceptions$OverflowException` after the 255-th emitted element is in the combination of `.onBackpressureError()` + `.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())` operators.

The `publishOn` operator uses an internal queue to manage the flow of data between the upstream and downstream operators when switching the execution context. If you open implementation of this operator you can see that it actually has one more argument:

```
public final Flux<T> publishOn(Scheduler scheduler) {
    return publishOn(scheduler, Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE);
}
```

The second argument is `prefetch` which is by default `Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE`, which is 256.

This queue overflows since the consumer consumes elements slower than the producer produces them. The strategy what to do in case of overflow you configured by `onBackpressureError()`. If you for example change it to `.onBackpressureBuffer(512)` you will have more capacity and get this error later, not after 255-th element.

As for the `requested` parameter. Since Project Reactor supports backpressure it works in the way when the consumer requests elements from the producer. By default, when you call `.subscribe()` method, consumer requests `UNBOUNDED` amount of elements. But different operators like `.publishOn` can change the number of requested elements. You can see it if you add more logging to your code, like this:

```java
.doOnRequest(requested -> System.out.println("# doOnRequest 2:" + requested))
.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
.doOnRequest(requested -> System.out.println("# doOnRequest 1:" + requested))
```

This prints

```
# doOnRequest 1:9223372036854775807  <--- which is UNBOUNDED
# doOnRequest 2:256                  <--- after .publishOn()
```